# Git Logs and Control per user

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I am investigating the possibility of using Git for code management for my Company. I have 2 questions in this regard:

1. We want extensive logs on each "clone" or "code access" per user. There has been past incidents where the 3rd party consultants tried to access the company's I.P., but there activities were logged. As of now, when I clone a Git repository, there is no log showing access of any such code.

   - Where must I get logs for this information?
   - More than that, if Git repository is cloned by some engineer, can we still get logs of further "cloning", if someone tries to clone from them?
2. Within same Git repository, is there a way to control access of certain parts of code? 
   For example, consider a repository named `TOP_DIR` with two subdirectories, `TOP_DIR/DIR_GLOBAL` and `TOP_DIR/DIR_SECURE`. I want to give read/write access on `DIR_SECURE` to only few team members, but full read/write to almost everyone for `DIR_GLOBAL`.

Any pointers in these regards will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why was this closed? This is directly related to software development. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions): "software tools commonly used by developers". This fits right in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for various inputs, this is what I ended up doing:--
(1) On server, I created 3 type of accounts.
(a) sudo 'ers account
(b) admin for repository -- linux group to control access of repository
(c) git user accounts with shell=/usr/bin/git-shell (so they cannot login directly)--added them with the same linux group.

The passwords were mailed to each team member. Whenever they access the system, ssl library records their access at /etc/log/auth_user.log. These logs are not quite enough, but some-where to start with.

Why I did not choose gitolite: Purpose of gitolite is to control access of selective parts of repository. Also, the product is not tested aggressively (as I can see lot of bugs still open) and more so, it does not log the access, nor can it differentiate b/w clone, or any other API. I am thinking of changing git code for being more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

git itself has no permission management at all.

You have to use a wrapper. Common is [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), which is based on ssh and uses private key authentication to authenticate users. You can give permissions based on the keys (i.e. the users) for each repository separately.

It would be easy to extend gitolite ([triggers?](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/triggers.html)) to log all unauthorized access attempts, by modifying the executable which is called as soon as ssh hands over to gitolite after authentication. Access by people who're not registered with gitolite at all would be logged by sshd/pam, as permission denied upon login.

As said, git doesn't do any authentication or authorization, so if you need directory based access control, you'd have to use submodules, which can behave itchy sometimes, but they'll do what you need.

Comment: Interesting, I'd heard of gitolite but never looked into it. Browsing through the [docs](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html), I don't see any logging options specified... am I missing something, or are you suggesting it could easily be setup via [hooks](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks)?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you can edit the executables of gitolite. Logging isn't built in, but it should be a one-liner to add it. Otherwise you can of course run hooks, but hooks will only be executed on successful access, so thats not what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I will look into Gitolite.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Git hooks to implement logging on a central server.  Gitolite is good for user management and will make sure any hooks get called.  With gitolite you can control who has access to what repos and with hooks can log user events.

You will ALWAYS have an issue with someone cloning a repo from another user's copy of the repo.  Git is decentralized so this is not a fool proof solution, but if no user lets anyone copy their repo, and you can make sure everyone uses the central server its a start.

If hooks are insufficient, check out http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/triggers.html  Gitolite does support "Triggers" that will give you a lot more info about what is going on that you can log.

Comment: See Jonas's comment on [his answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13586525/168775). Hooks may not be a good solution as (he suggests that) hooks are only run on successful access, and would miss actions such as failed login attempts.

Comment: For failures you could monitor the ssh access logs, should be logged in /var/log/secure.log  I like hooks a lot because you don't have to worry about patching future versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git-measure to get statistics per user.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please be a bit more detailed in your answer.